# click event listener only works on first list item generated from mongoDB and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am fetching records from mongoDB and showing them in an unordered list. I have given the delete link a data-id which holds the product ID. For now I am just alerting the id when I click on the button. But for some reason the alert only pops up if I click on the first item. If I click on any item after that nothing happens and I get no error in console.

```
<% for (const products of pending) { %>
 <li>
    <a href="#" class="button gray delete" data-id="<%= products._id %>"><i class="sl sl-icon-close"></i> Delete</a>
 </li>
<% } %>

<script>
    const deleteBtn = document.querySelector('.delete');
    const productId = deleteBtn.getAttribute('data-id');
    document.querySelector('.delete').addEventListener('click', e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert(productId);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `querySelector()` only returns one element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to create an event listener for a lot of dynamically generated elements, you should use a delegated event listener:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (!event.target.matches('.delete')) return;

  const btn = event.target;
  const productId = btn.dataset.id;

  event.preventDefault();
  alert(productId);
});
```

Instead of `body` you should use the most direct ancestor of all the elements that match `.delete` so you're not wasting time running a handler for a lot of irrelevant click events.

#### References:

- [`matches()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches)
- [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

Comment: Thanks so much for this, it works and I appreciate the explanation and references.

Comment: I am having a hard time trying to find info on how to target the most direct ancestor instead of using `document.body`. Would you be willing to give me a clue?

Comment: Use your best judgment. It's just a guideline for improved performance but since you're not using a framework of any sort, it shouldn't make much of a difference in practice.